# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Быстро и почти не задумываясь (?) делаю уроки и плюхаюсь в кровать.
2. Теперь я выгляжу (?) как все.

**Заранее спасибо!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Деепричастный оборот не обособляется, ***"если оборот выступает в качестве однородного члена в паре с необособленным обстоятельством, например: Алёша длинно и как-то прищурив глаза посмотрел на Ракитина (Достоевский)"***. [здесь](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/95/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)
Так что в первом предложении запятая не нужна.

Второе предложение также оформляем без запятой, так как сказуеме здесь ВЫГЛЯЖУ КАК ВСЕ.

Answer (score 2):

В приведенных примерах запятая не нужна.

В первом деепричастие тесно связано со сказуемым, поэтому запятая не требуется (смысл в том, каким именно образом автор делает упражнение, а не в том, что он делает упражнение и одновременно не задумывается).

Во втором случае запятая не нужна, т.к. оборот с **как** тесно связан со сказуемым, и предложение  без такого оборота не имеет законченного смысла.

Answer (score 0):

В первом нет, во втором да.